# How to set Input field width using em and to disable it to extend on content area?

Tags: html, css, input, width

see this [FIDDLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/stq23frr/) and [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m/jvt/) ,try to resize your window browser then scroll to the right and see the input field extending itself.

I try to use `%` as width that I knew that is `relative` width to its containing `<div>` but on minimize browser size,the `input` field reduces it size or shrink.

To be clearer,my question is how can I set input field using 'em' or `px` without extending to content area when browser is minimize?

Any help is much appreciated or any suggestion?

Comment: The fiddle demo is not working, the link is leading to nowhere

Comment: @Shadi the link works fine sir,It shows a blue header..

Comment: anyways, are you shrinking the DIV also with the input field? how do you measure the size of the DIV that contains the input?

Comment: @Shadi , also see this http://jsfiddle.net/stq23frr/ for my html and css

Comment: Can you point to the filed that you have problem with? or would you please rephrase your question?

Comment: If you will resize the browser into smaller window sir, notice the input field will extends to content area. @Shadi

Comment: @Shadi,try to resize your window browser then scroll to the right and see the input field extending itself.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 50px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in general if you want to design for a web you need to set some general rules, like the following:

-- Widths should be %

-- Margins and Padding should be absolute values

You can read more about this responsive web design concept, [an excellent book](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design)

The following would be a start for you to design a responsive web design:

```
<style>
    #maincontainer
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 68.1%; /* 740 / 1600 */
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #header
    {
        width:100%;
        margin:10px;
    }

    #sideBarContentWrapper
    {
        width:100%;
        margin:10px;
    }

    #contentContainer
    {
        width:100%;
    }

    .custominput
    {
        width:70%;
    }

    #content
    {
        width:100%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        .custominput {
            width: 50%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
        .custominput {
            width: 40%;
    }
}
</style>

<div id="mainContainer">

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Sample header 1</h1>
        <h2>Sample header 2</h2>
        <h4>Sample header 3</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- header, END -->

    <div id="sideBarContentWrapper">

        <div id="contentContainer">

            <div id="content">
                <label>Sample Label 1</label><input type='text' class="custominput">
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Sample Label 2</label><input type='text' class="custominput">
            </div>
            <!-- content, END -->

        </div>
        <!-- contentContainer, END -->

        <div id="sideBar">


            <p>This is some sample text to go in the side bar</p>


        </div>
        <!-- sideBar, END -->

        <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- sideBarContentWrapper, END -->

</div>
<!-- mainContainer, END -->
```